# how can I confirm a transfer is valid by rpc result?

Tags: rpc, transfer

I am a developer of a crypto currency exchange, I want to find deposit to my address from each tezos block. After I call the rpc /chains/main/blocks/height, I got the result. And I find there are many `balance_updates` in the result, should I use `balance_updates` to judge deposit? And how to verify `balance_updates` is valid? Where is the document about tezos block structure or about rpc result. I see the doc at https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html?highlight=operation_result#get-chains-chain-id-blocks has not detail info about rpc result.

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to read all new blocks and find blocks that send tokens to your account? I think you should use the https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id to get each block, then use the operations api to get the operations in each block: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html?highlight=operation_result#get-block-id-operations
Also consider using an indexer such as tzstats: https://github.com/blockwatch-cc/tzindex

Comment: what's means of ```..``` of rpc url? What's whole url of https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id

Comment: `/chains/<chain_id>/`, where `chain_id` can be e.g. `main`. So your full url is `/chains/<chain_id>/block/<block_id>`. The head of a chain can be referred to by `head`. So to get the head of the main chain, try `/chains/main/block/head`.